# Why interpolation gives different results than a gradient?

Tags: opengl

I have differents grayscale textures of a height of one pixel, with `GL_LINEAR` interpolation.
Texture `T(k)` is made of a gradient from left to right of `k` pixels from `0` (black) to `255` (white).

Examples :

```
T(2) = 0 255
T(3) = 0 128 255
T(4) = 0 85 170 255
T(256) = 0 1 2 ... 255
```

Some examples rendered are there :

`T(002)=` [image]

`T(003)=`[image]

`T(004)=`[image]

`T(255)=`[image]

Why textures do have different results ? The gradient appears more nicely arranged when more pixels are used.

In practice, I can't use less pixel to render a nice gradient to save memory if I want the same result. I suppose the "right" gradient is the one with the most pixels, `T(256)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why textures do have different results ? The gradient appears more nicely arranged when more pixels are used.

Because your assumptions on the texture coordinates are wrong, `s=0.0` is the left *edge* of the left texel, and `1.0` the right edge of the rightmost one.

For a texture with width 2, the texel centers are at `0.25` and `0.75`, and if you sample outside of that range, your wrap mode (which in your case seems to be `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`) will apply.

If you want to see a linear gradient, you'll have to go from `1/(2*width)` to `1-1/(2*width)`. If you increase the `width`, these values will of course move closer to `0` and `1`, so it converges to the result you want when `width` approaches infinity.